# Clang-format with 8-space rule for complex if statements in Java

Tags: java, indentation, clang-format

I'm trying to set-up clang-format so that it confirms to Oracle's [Java Code Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf). The document provides numerous examples, of which the most important are:

```java
function(longExpression1, longExpression2, longExpression3,
         longExpression4, longExpression5);

var = function1(longExpression1,
                function2(longExpression2,
                          longExpression3));

longName1 = longName2 * (longName3 + longName4 - longName5)
            + 4 * longname6;

if ((condition1 && condition2)
       || (condition3 && condition4)
       ||!(condition5 && condition6)) {
    doSomethingAboutIt();
}
```

The following options cover the first three cases:

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align 
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
ColumnLimit:     80
IndentWidth:     4
TabWidth:        8
```

About the fourth case, the document says: "Line wrapping for `if` statements should generally use the 8-space rule, since conventional (4 space) indentation makes seeing the body difficult." I went through all options, but I don't think I came across something.

Its admittedly a rather fastidious issue, but I thought maybe there is something I overlooked. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You code isn't java. Can you clarify what is the objective?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, pringi! Sorry, I realize my original post was a bit terse. The objective is to set up clang-format so that it would auto-indent in accordance with the principles of Oracle's Java Code Conventions. As in this document, I left out the embedding in a class as that would be of no relevance.

I'm particularly interested in the `if` statement. With the settings above clang-format would align the "|" operators with the parentheses. To be consistent with the guidelines I would prefer for it to put 8 spaces before the "|" instead (if that is possible with clang).